# Getting the Java Version I want in a SunOS account

Tags: sunos, .profile

I have an account on a Unix server.  I can't get it to point to the version of Java I want when I am in BASH.

The version of Unix is:

```
SunOS 5.10 Generic January 2005
```

This is what I have in my .profile:

```
#====================================================================
#   set the environment
#====================================================================

ANT_HOME=/apps1/apache-ant-1.8.4
export ANT_HOME

#  $PATH:/user1/acme21 needs to be included to make anything work
PATH=.:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0_24:$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH:/user1/acme21
export PATH

JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0_24
export JAVA_HOME

CLASSPATH=.:/user1/sterus01/TestProgramsLib/mail.jar:/user1/sterus01/TestProgramsLib/activation.jar:/user1/sterus01/TestProgramsLib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/user1/sterus01/TestProgramsLib/mail.jar:ojdbc14.jar
export CLASSPATH

env | grep DIS

# Use the bash shell, get many conveniences
bash
```

When I run echo $JAVA_HOME and echo $PATH I get

```
bash-3.00$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0_24
bash-3.00$
```

and

```
bash-3.00$ echo $PATH
.:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0_24:/apps1/apache-ant-1.8.4/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/etc:/usr/ucb:/usr/local/sudo:/usr/local/sbin:/user1/acme21
bash-3.00$
```

Yet "which javac" reveals:

```
bash-3.00$ which javac
/usr/bin/javac
bash-3.00$
```

and "which java" reveals:

```
bash-3.00$ which java
/usr/bin/java
bash-3.00$
```

Is there anything I can do to get it to point to the Java version I specified in my .profile file?

Thanks in advance
Happy Holidays
Steve

Comment: I do not agree with my question being closed and voted down.  I do not agree because I think getting the version of Java I want set up in a Unix account is about programming and is about software development.  That is what I was trying to do when I ran into the problem that led to me creating the post.  No disrespect.  I value the moderation at stackoverflow.  It is nice to ask a question without getting slammed, like on Usenet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this:

```
PATH=.:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0_24
```

isn't right, and you need instead

```
PATH=.:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0_24/bin
```

to pick up the binary directory *within* that Java installation.

p.s. I wouldn't put the current directory (.) in your `PATH`. Otherwise someone can substitute a trojan-like program (e.g. a substitute for `ls`) in a directory. You'll pick that up when you cd into the containing directory and type `ls` (there's an entertaining story relating to this in the **Unix Power Tools** book)

Comment: That was it!  Thanks.  Thaks for the tip about removing the current directory from the path as well.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your `java` and `javac` executables are in `/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0_24` ? Perhaps they are in `/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/`.